# HTML5 date input, saving to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, date

I'm having a bit of trouble, and can't seem to find any solid answers. BUt hoping someone could help.

I have an HTML5 input form that gets a chosen date

```
<input type="date" name="launch_date" />
```

This brings up the datepicker, and enters the date in dd/mm/yy

I'm trying to save this to a SQL database, that using the DATE type in the table. So first I make variables of all the form inputs

```
$launch_date = $_POST['launch_date'];
```

And then I've tried to convert the string to a proper timestamp so it can be accepted in the database.

Then all the variables are added into the correct columns as part of the SQL INSERT/UPDATE query.

```
$launch_date = strtotime($launch_date);
```

Whenever I look into the database though, it's just always showing 0000-00-00, like it's expecting a YYYY-MM-DD format.

How can I get it so that the date entered on the front end is DD-MM-YYYY, but stored in the database correctly as YYYY-MM-DD?

UPDATE

Okay, so I think I was trying to make it too complicated. By using the HTML5 date input, and saving that input directly to the database into a DATA type column, saves it as YYY-MM-DD. Seems to work fine.

When I echo these values, it will output for example 2014-09-24. How can I make it show 24-09-2014?

```
<?php echo $row['start_date'];?>
```

Comment: If it's stored in the database as a date, it's stored correctly.  Formatting only matters when you are displaying the data.

Comment: But it's not storing it in the database, it's showing as 0000-00-00

Comment: What is the database column type?

Comment: The column type is DATE

Comment: Sorry I've just got what you meant. It's only the pull back from the database that needs formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Note that [`stringToTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a Unix Timestamp (ie. the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC) which might not be what your database is expecting.

Bare in mind that the *presentational* value may differ depending on the browser and the the user's locale but the *actual* value submitted should be a ["A valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339]"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

Here's a little demo:

```
<?php 
$launch_date = $_POST['launch_date'];
echo '$launch_date = \''.$launch_date.'\' <br />';
$launch_date = strtotime($launch_date);
echo 'strtotime($launch_date) = \''.$launch_date.'\' '; //a unix timestamp eg '1410480000'
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="date" name="launch_date" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

http://runnable.com/VCLkST-wq9cPvwJT/stackoverflow-com-questions-26020544-for-php

**UPDATE**

Further to your change of question. You can format the date using [PHP's DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), like this:

```
<?php echo date_format($row['start_date'], 'd-m-Y');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify in JQuery date picker itself.

```
$( "#launch_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

This function will come up with MySQL Date-Time format.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at strtotime().
Let's replace that line by this instead:

```
list($day,$mon,$year) = explode('/', $launch_date);
$launch_date = "$year-$mon-$day";
```

Comment: When trying to process, I get undefined offset 0 and 1 on this line (list...)

Comment: That means your error is from "$launch_date = $_POST['launch_date'];"
Please check if you are using POST method in the form, and also print out $_POST['launch_date'] to see if you get the user input correctly.

Edit: I saw you wrote you entered the date as enters dd/mm/yy, but below you said you want to enter in DD-MM-YYYY. Please confirm what you want. In the "explode('/',$launch_date)", I assumed that you were using dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: I have updated my question, trying to make it simpler

Comment: Your update is still not clear about which format you are using: dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy (/ or -)?
And about your last question (How can I make it show 24-09-2014), you can format using MySQL with: DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%d-%m-%Y").

Comment: Attention that you have 2 problems: (1) formating input and put into database, and (2) show again data from DB in your preferred format.

Comment: Whether it's dashes or slashes, I'm not really bothered about. It was the order that I was trying to explain.

Comment: Yes but in my above solution, the error you got "undefined offset 0 and 1" might come from there, because I assumed you were using '/' but you might enter '-'.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience a lot of the problems boil down to the locale settings on the server.

PHP might be recognising dd/mm/yyyy as mm/dd/yyyy and having a fit if the day part is invalid.  To make PHP validate the date correctly as dd/mm/yyyy, swap the / for - (dd-mm-yyyy) when

```
$launch_date = $_POST['launch_date'];
$launch_date = str_replace("/", "-", $launch_date);
$launch_date = strtotime($launch_date);
```

This is just a quick hack to see if it's the case.  If not, then I'd recommend at the very least putting in var_dumps along the way to check that the date is properly formatted along the way.

Another way is to parse the date, along with the format it's to be parsed in with date_create_from_format (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
$launch_date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $launch_date );
```

I don't think there's an implementation on Windows PHP... so if you're having bother, here's a functional implementation

```
if (!function_exists('date_parse_from_format')) {

    function date_parse_from_format($format, $date) {
        $returnArray = array('hour' => 0, 'minute' => 0, 'second' => 0,
            'month' => 0, 'day' => 0, 'year' => 0);

        $dateArray = array();

        // array of valid date codes with keys for the return array as the values
        $validDateTimeCode = array('Y' => 'year', 'y' => 'year',
            'm' => 'month', 'n' => 'month',
            'd' => 'day', 'j' => 'day',
            'H' => 'hour', 'G' => 'hour',
            'i' => 'minute', 's' => 'second');

        /* create an array of valid keys for the return array
         * in the order that they appear in $format
         */
        for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($format) - 1; $i++) {
            $char = substr($format, $i, 1);

            if (array_key_exists($char, $validDateTimeCode)) {
                $dateArray[$validDateTimeCode[$char]] = '';
            }
        }

        // create array of reg ex things for each date part
        $regExArray = array('.' => '\.', // escape the period
            // parse d first so we dont mangle the reg ex
            // day
            'd' => '(\d{2})',
            // year
            'Y' => '(\d{4})',
            'y' => '(\d{2})',
            // month
            'm' => '(\d{2})',
            'n' => '(\d{1,2})',
            // day
            'j' => '(\d{1,2})',
            // hour
            'H' => '(\d{2})',
            'G' => '(\d{1,2})',
            // minutes
            'i' => '(\d{2})',
            // seconds
            's' => '(\d{2})');

        // create a full reg ex string to parse the date with
        $regEx = str_replace(array_keys($regExArray), array_values($regExArray), $format);

        // Parse the date
        preg_match("#$regEx#", $date, $matches);

        // some checks...
        if (!is_array($matches) ||
                $matches[0] != $date ||
                sizeof($dateArray) != (sizeof($matches) - 1)) {
            return $returnArray;
        }

        // an iterator for the $matches array
        $i = 1;

        foreach ($dateArray AS $key => $value) {
            $dateArray[$key] = $matches[$i++];

            if (array_key_exists($key, $returnArray)) {
                $returnArray[$key] = $dateArray[$key];
            }
        }

        return $returnArray;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Just in case this was missed... make sure that you're then converting it into YYYY-MM-DD when it's going into the DB:

```
// Whatever you do to parse date into timestamp
$launch_date_db = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $launch_date)
```

**UPDATE**

PHP likes timestamps... so go with that:

```
$launch_date = strtotime($row['start_date']); // convert it into timestamp
echo date('d-m-Y', $launch_date); // format timestamp
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php <- examples of PHP accepted date formats.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the proper format with SQL:

```
.... VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('24-09-2014', '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Getting it back

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM ......
```